# How to Rank a Measure which is Average Field, Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new in Power bi. I have a table where I have agents details. I have their scores as well. I have date wise data into table where the following columns are available  - 
[image: Raw Data]

I have created created measure for Average of Score where Metric is UES AGGREGATE -

[image: Report Preview]

I have to get the ranking of the advocate(s) for the Average Score (UES AGG). I have tried this measure for Ranking calculation -

Rank_UES = RANKX('RankSummary',[RKS_UESAGG])

I am getting wrong ranking. Please help me , how to solve the issue.

Thanking You.

Comment: Note : The Advocate Name used into slicer. So, it can be selected. When they are selected. I have to show the ranking for selected agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ALL function with RANKX.

```
Rank_UES  =
RANKX (
    ALL ( 'RankSummary'[AgentfullName] ),
    [RKS_UESAGG]
)
```

I do not know if your [RKS_UESAGG] get you what you want. Suppose you want average sales you make something like this:

```
Rank_UES =
RANKX (
    ALL ( 'RankSummary'[AgentfullName] ),
    AVERAGE ( 'RankSummary'[Amount] )
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax

Comment: Hi,

[RKS_UESAGG] is nothing but I am getting Average of [Score] only for [Metric] = "UES AGGREGATE". 

Even, I tried the 2nd approach for all [Metric]. However, the ranking is not looks correct.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Make your example simple. Input just 6 rows, remove irrelevant columns. Paste expected results.